# Finding 3 dimentional B-spline controll points from given array of points from spline solution?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, interpolation, approximation

Wa are talking about [Non-uniform rational B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline). We have some simple 3 dimentional array like

```
{1,1,1}
{1,2,3}
{1,3,3}
{2,4,5}
{2,5,6}
{4,4,4}
```

Which are points from a plane created by some B-spline

How to find controll points of spline that created that plane? (I know its a hard task because of weights that need to be calculated but I really hope it is solvable)

[image] For thouse who did not got idea of question - sory my writting is wwbad - we have points that are part of plane rendered here and we need to find controll points that form a spline which solution is that rendered plane.

Comment: If you Google for "surface reconstruction B-spline" you'll find a lot of results. But the algorithms are not general enough for any mesh, so you'll have to dig up if your mesh matches the one used by some algorithm.

Comment: Do you know the values of the knots? If you do that makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Is this still relevant?  You should understand that there is not a unique solution to this problem.  I'm pretty sure that multiple, different B-splines can all generate the same set of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several interpolation techniques that could be used, Global NURB surface interpolation, or Bi-cubic piecewise surface interpolation are reasonable.

"The NURBS book" by Les A. Piegl covers a number of them